# Android daily sending mail

Tags: android, email

I want to send an email every day to some users.I have created the classes for sending the mail.What should I use for sending it background every day?Also I would like application sending the message even if the user has not used the app that day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AlarmManager to schedule and run your email sending code. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

You can find a lot of tutorials e.g. http://code4reference.com/2012/07/tutorial-on-android-alarmmanager/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do background operations in Android that run on a schedule you will need to use AlarmManager.

Best example for this is here: [AlarmManager example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example)